# Writing data in new line with bold in sharing gmail android

Tags: android

i want to write with bold and new line style while sharing data with gmail. i have tried with \n or you can say  but i could not get result my code is below ..

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
        intent.setType("plain/text");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, emailAddressList);  
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, emailSubject); 
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "<b>Hi this is test app</b> <br/> your first app is this"); 
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choice App t send email:"));
```

but it is not showing with bold and with new line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try out below code it's working fine :) i have tested

```
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("mailto:"+emailAddressList));
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, emailSubject);
                shareIntent.putExtra(
                Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                Html.fromHtml(new StringBuilder()
                    .append("<p><b>Hi this is test app</b></p>")
                    .append("<small><p>Hi this is test app</small>")
                    .toString()));

                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Choice App t send email:"));
```