# bold text in emailintent

Tags: java, android

when I try to use < b > test < /b > in my email, it dosent work.
But it understand the html tag < br >

is it not possible to bold text ?

```
if (v == pdfButton) {
                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(edit.getText().toString())) {                        
                        generatePDF();          
                        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        //String aEmailList[] = { "user@fakehost.com","user2@fakehost.com" };
                        String aEmailCCList[] = { "ma@rhk.dk"};     

                        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_CC, aEmailCCList);
                        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Førsyn");
                        //emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, FILE_URI);
                        // emailIntent.setType("pdf");
                            emailIntent.setType("text/html");
                            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new        
                            File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"+ edit.getText().toString() + ".pdf")));


                            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,Html.fromHtml("Brug af afkalker" +
                                "<br>" +
                                "Fliser:"+
                                "<br>" +
                                "Når du skal bruge det på dine fliser, skal du gøre fliserne/fugerne våde med din bruser først, det er vigtigt at du gør det, da fugerne er lavet af kalk, så hvis de ikke er våde, vil det ”æde” fugerne, afdække vandhanen med en pose(da afkalkningsmiddel er så stærkt at det får sorte pletter, hvis det kommer på)"+
                                "<br>" +
                                "Du kommer afkalker på en svamp (du skal bruge mindst 1/3 del af flasken bare til fliserne alene) og det er ufortyndet, og gnubber(med den grove side) fliser og fuger rene, lade det sidde i 15 min. og gnub en ekstra gang, skyld efter med vand, bagefter gør du rent med alm. Ajax." +
                                "<br>"+
                                "<br>"+
                                "<b>"+
                                "Vask:"+
                                "</b>"+
                                "<br>"+
                                "Det eneste du skal passe på her, er vandhanen, afkalkeren må ikke komme på vandhanen, da den får sorte pletter."+
                                "<br>"+
                                "<br>"+
                                "<b>Toilet:</b>"+
```

part of the mail I get

Vask:

Det eneste du skal passe på her, er vandhanen, afkalkeren må ikke komme på vandhanen, da den får sorte pletter.

Toilet:

Det skal bare hældes ufortyndet i og sidde i mange timer og skrubbes godt med en børste. Hvis du ikke kan få det rent, kan du låne en pimpsten på kontoret, som fjerne alt snavs.

I tried to make the word Vask bold, and the word Toilet.

Any help?

Comment: There are many mail clients for Android. None of them are required to support HTML.

Comment: but how come it understand the tag < br  > then ?

Comment: Because the developers of whatever email client you are trying wrote support for that, presumably replacing it with newlines. Nobody is forcing them to do that (or to honor tags that they do not), and not all email clients will necessarily pay attention to `<br>` either.

Answer (score 0):

`<br>` isn't terminated, your better of doing `<br/>` as it's just a line break.

If you want to bold your text surround it in `<strong> text to bold </strong>`

Comment: thanks for the / in br. But strong dont work, the text is still not bold

Comment: try putting it all in a new StringBuilder()  - as per this stackoverflow q/a - : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13026414/writing-data-in-new-line-with-bold-in-sharing-gmail-android    - I have no idea why a stringbuilder .toString() is any different to what you've done however in any event it is more efficient based on how many + + + you have. Maybe it's the URi.parse that's doing it.  Oh - Also remove your "emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new       File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"+ edit.getText().toString() + ".pdf")));"  - its no longer a stream

Comment: ok I will try. But I need the string, it is making a pdf file, with a edittext value (diffent every time)

Comment: same thing no bold text :(

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html), `Html` doesn't support all tags. Have you tried the `<strong>` or `<em>` tags?

Comment: strong and em have no effect